# Wiring question regarding switching wire gauge within a circuit

Tags: electrical

I have a 20 amp circuit that was run with 10AWG underground to an outside GFCI outlet. Can I switch to running 12 awg (since its 20 amp) to have a light and switch after the GFCI?

Comment: 10 AWG is larger than 12 AWG, and you're *always* allowed to use bigger wire than is mandated.  So there's no code benefit to downgrading 10 to 12.   Keep using it and keep it at 20A.

Comment: @Harper, but #10 copper is significantly stiffer making it difficult for connections in a box--folding. Do ordinary receptacles accept #10 wire? If one were going to continue with #10 would you advocate pigtailing with #12 for each receptacle and using #12 for switch loops and light fixtures?

Comment: @JimStewart sure, pigtail for #12 or any size that is also legal.  Any part of the circuit can be any oversize, but all must be minimum size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Go for it

Since it's a 20A circuit, you can use any wire size 12AWG or larger to run it.  (The existing 10AWG may have simply been what the original installer had on hand, or may have been installed for voltage drop control reasons.)

Comment: It was for voltage drop!  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jason -- we show our thanks here by upvoting and accepting answers :)